# Edit autogenerated email, and continue program only when/if it is sent

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook

I have a program that generates an email (outlook) using data from a database (access). I want the database to be updated if the email is sent, but not if it is not sent. I am looking for a way to "pause" the program until the user has disposed of the email, either by sending it, or by canceling it. Here is what I have (that does not work the way I want):

```
    Dim OutApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem

    OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon()

    OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
    With OutMail
        .To = recipient
        .Subject = subject
        .BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
        .Body = htmlBody                
        .Display()
    End With

    If OutMail.Sent Then
        'Code that is to be run if the email is sent
    Else
        'Code that is to be run if the email is not sent
    End If
```

The problem with this is that the answer to the If is always 'false' because the program keeps running while the user is checking the email, and by the time the email is eventually sent, the 'else'-code has already run.

So my question is: Is there a way to make the program wait and see if the email gets sent?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim OutApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem

OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon()

OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
With OutMail
    .To = recipient
    .Subject = subject
    .BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
    .Body = htmlBody                
    .Display()
End With

' *** NEW CODE:
Dim numberOfAttempts As Integer = 10
While Not OutMail.Sent And numberOfAttempts > 0
    numberOfAttempts -= 1
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000) ' Wait 10 seconds and retry
End While

If numberOfAttempts > 0 Then
    'Code that is to be run if the email is sent
Else
    'Code that is to be run if the email is not sent
End If
```

---

Catastrophic patch, but it will probably work:

```
' WARNING : WORST. CODE. EVER.
Dim numberOfAttempts As Integer = 10
While numberOfAttempts > 0
    Try
        If OutMail.Sent Then Exit While
    Catch ex As Exception
        'apparently "exception" = "success" ..... so there we go:
        Exit While
    End Try
    numberOfAttempts -= 1
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000) ' Wait 10 seconds and retry
End While

If numberOfAttempts > 0 Then
    'Code that is to be run if the email is sent
Else
    'Code that is to be run if the email is not sent
End If
```

Comment: Good idea to run a "while-loop" as a "pause", but It doesnt quite work. If I cancel the email, it runs fine, but if I send it I get "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException"

Comment: Without more information, my guess is that the property OutMail.Sent is not available after the email has been successfully sent. [This guy](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2639d00a-0d06-4967-8b0a-6d734ec4aa7a/make-access-wait-until-outlook-message-sent-from-outbox-then-return-explorer-focus-from-outlook-back?forum=accessdev) made it work by checking the outbox (code at the bottom of the page), which seems CRAZY to me. If I were you I would seriously consider using the custom .NET library System.Net.Mail.MailMessage instead of outlook. Regards.

Comment: I have edited the code to make it work. Be VERY careful if you use it, because of course the error in the catch can be anything else other than a substitute for "email successfully sent". But the alternate solution (checking the outbox) seems almost as bad to me.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help. I think I have to reconsider the approach. It would be beter if I can somehow "edit" the contents of the email in the program itself, and then send it directly. Back to the drawingboard, I guess :-)

Comment: At this point I have rewritten the program using a simple msgBox asking the user if he sent the e-mail.
The point is that the database needs to show if the email was sent or not, and updating it when the email is created might cause problems if the email is not sent after all.

Comment: One might say that rely on the user to decide is as risky as the try-catch solution. Another horribly complicated but reliable solution would be to send a "control email" in BCC with the original email, and then make the code listen to the reception of this copy.

Answer (score 0):

Confirming that an email has been delivered is kind of tricky. Monitoring the Outbox (e.g. via the Folder.Items.ItemAdd/ItemMove events for the Outbox) is a BAD idea as touching any items in that folder usually breaks the send for that item.

You can monitor the MailItem.Send event for the compose email, and that's probably sufficient but you'll have to assume the email will be delivered according to the user's Send/Receive Groups and settings. But you can monitor those sending events via SyncObject.SyncStart/SyncEnd events for each S/R group. If the event matches the account used to send the email, you can possibly check the Outbox's Items.Count value to verify that it was delivered.